# Which Issue Tracker is suitable for a VPS?

Tags: bug-tracking, trac, redmine, mantis

I'm hosting my application on a [Linode](http://www.linode.com/), but is hosted on a Tomcat instance, which uses most of the RAM. I also have Apache installed, so I can front Mercurial, and I believe a bug tracker is a must, however I can't decide on which is best, given scarce resources. JIRA seems to be out of the question, so I've been deciding on either

- Trac
- Mantis
- Redmine

I like Trac because I have already got Apache serving Python, Redmine for the features and Mantis because I feel it's the most lightweight of the three, however lacking in the feature department, compared with the other two, so, what do you recommend, given the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Whats a VPS?)

That aside, do you really need to maintain your own bug tracking installation? We have moved our system from an inhouse Bugzilla to Assembla (www.assembla.com) and it is great! I have a lot more time to do my actual job these days instead of dealing with multi-tool integration problems. For the record I think Trac is part of Assembla's integration. We are a small organization so the Assembla fees are pretty light, I think we're up to maybe $25/mo (including all of our SVN hosting) so that's about 10 minutes of my time (wink;) and I was easily spending 1/2 day a month on tools issues. You'd have to scope it out to see if their offering makes sense for your organization. (BTW I don't work for Assembla!)

My apologies to give you a non-technical answer to your technical question.

Comment: VPS, Virtual Private Server, which is what Linode, Slicehost and many others call its hosting services. They're usually a virtual Xen instance. Anyway, thanks for the heads up on Assembla, i'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I have a VPS and Redmine.

We used to have a 1 gig RAM, single v-core, 40GB disk VPS running Centos 5.5 (x64).  It struggled with performance issues with Redmine under heavy use (since we also have our e-commerce websites running on the same box).  We only have two developers that access redmine at a time, but we have enough apps that there were times that our FTP and Redmine and SVN access was slowing down the server and affecting our e-commerce customers (bad!).

We upgraded to a 2 gig RAM, two v-core, 80GB disk VPS.  Chances are if we ever hire contractor software dev's and they use our Redmine and SVN we would probably re-size our slice to a 4 gig RAM, four v-core VPS.  Still experimenting to see if 2 gig and two vcores is enough for us now.  Basically you should be spending at least $50-$100 a month on your server for it to have enough to run redmine.

Answer (score 0):

Mantis is quite lightweight and works well on small VPSs. I would expect it to fit nicely on a 512M slice, and perhaps on an even smaller one, depending on your traffic.

I see that you believe it to be less featured that Redmine and Trac . That's another discussion, but the question is - does it do enough for *your* needs? If it does, you have a winner.